# How to write "?", "(" in java string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace

I need an array like this:

```
String [] x = {",",".",":",";","&","?","!","(",")"};
```

but for these characters, it doesn't work properly: ".", "?" ,"(", ")".
When I'm trying to replace them in a string:

```
String z = "Hell&o Wor.ld!";

for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++){

if(z.contains(x[i])){

    System.out.println(z.replaceAll(x[i],""));
 }}
```

it doesn't work for these four characters. How can I fix that?

Comment: Use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. `replace` doesn't use regular expressions like `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll` uses regular expression interpretations of those characters, so you need to escape them. You also need to escape the backslash for the sake of the string parser:

```
String [] x = {",", "\\.", ":", ";", "&", "\\?", "!", "\\(", "\\)"};
```

And since you have escape characters in here too, you need to change your contains check to only check the last character in the matching string:

```
String z = "Hell&o Wor.ld!";

for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if( z.contains( x[i].substring(x[i].length() - 1) )) { // if z contains last char of x
        System.out.println(z.replaceAll(x[i],""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forger that backslash itself needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Cause: [String.replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))
takes a regex as first argument,
and in the Java regex grammar `.?()` are special chars

---

1. Escape them:

   ```
   String[] x = {",", "\\.", ":", ";", "&", "\\?", "!", "\\(", "\\)"};
   ```

   But the condition can"t work anymore, you need something like

   ```
   if (z.matches(".*" + x[i] + ".*")) {
   ```
2. Use  [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char))

   ```
   System.out.println(z.replace(x[i], ""));
   ```

--